# Get last inserted id after setting commit to false

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into two tables, if the insertion not work for one of them operation should ignored.(I think this called transaction)

```
try{
    $dbcon=new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$dbn);
    if($dbcon->connect_error)
        throw new Exception($dbcon->connect_error);

    $dbcon->autocommit(false);

    $query="insert into users(id,email) values(null,'$email')";
    $res_a=$dbcon->$query($query);

    if($res_a){
        $l_id=$res_a->insert_id;
        $query="insert into profiles values($l_id,'$name','$birthday')";
        $res_b=$dbcon->query($query);
    }

    if(!res_a || !res_b){
        $dbcon->rollback();
        throw new Exception("problem with database !!");
    }

    $dbcon->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}finaly{
    if(isset($dbcon))
    $dbcon->close();
}
```

With this code PHP showing this Error : "Trying to get property of non-object" ...

In other words is there better  way to do transaction without using autocommit methode (I'm working with mysqli)?

Comment: You will have to commit the first query so that it's inserted into the database before getting the inserted ID.

Comment: @Matt But if I do that and in the case of the second query failed I will need to delete the inserted user !... I I'm looking for better way !

Comment: You could always fetch the highest id, add 1 to it and assume that this is going to be the inserted ID. This is a really bad idea for concurrency control unless you lock the table though.

Comment: @Matt because this is failing them for one thing `values($l_id,$name,$birthday)` so unless those are ALL integers (which name I highly doubt) then that is failing them unless it's intentional; which I also doubt. and Blaatpraat's link is also valid, it answers the error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is to do with issues to do with committing data in the correct format, not query errors.

Comment: @Matt *"With this code PHP showing this Error : "Trying to get property of non-object" ..."* what am I not grasping here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will edit the question by adding quotes but this will not fix the problem ...

Comment: @BBeta what is the question really about here? You obviously have a syntax error in `values($l_id,$name,$birthday)` so I have no idea what you're trying to do, throw an intentional error? How can you complete the transaction if your `values($l_id,$name,$birthday)` is failing you? You're probably not using exceptions neither http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and that alone would have thrown you a totally different error message. `$name` is very most likely a string and not an integer, therefore it too needs to be quoted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The confusion is because you marked the question as a duplicate of another question, while the questions themselves are not duplicates at all. The answer to that question might help in answering this one, but saying they are duplicates just adds to the confusion.

Comment: the quetions in other words how to insert data into two tables (Ex : users and profiles) using transaction and mysqli .. I put the code just as an exemple ..

Comment: Just a quick sanity check if you dont mind! What database engine are you using please? Is it MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: @BBeta I suggest you do (add the proper quotes) and then try it again, then come back and tell us any other errors you may be getting and use error handling http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @GolezTrol fair enough, I removed it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's InnoDB

Comment: So are you still getting the error __Error : "Trying to get property of non-object"__ and if so at what line are you getting the error. Remember we can only work with the information you give us, and that error is always due to a failed `query()` not being correctly handled

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... Yes, maybe I just need to work without transaction ... inserting data to user table then getting user id from it then inserting data to profiles and if it doesn't work I have to delete inserted row from user table

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the contents of `$l_id` to see if you have a new id returned, like this `$l_id=$res_a->insert_id; echo $l_id;` This must be possible within a transaction or transactions would be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question and ignoring the issues with the error message this is how to run multiple updates within a transaction.

I would try retrieving the `->insert_id` using the connection handle rather than the statement handle as the transaction/commit/rollback are all part of the connection handle and not the statement handle this appears to be more reliable and may be why you are not getting the error.

```
$dbcon=new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$dbn);
// if no connection can be made there is no point doing anything else
if($dbcon->connect_error) {
    echo $dbcon->connect_error;
    exit;
}

try{

    //$dbcon->autocommit(false);
    $dbcon->begin_transaction();  // this does the autocommit = false as well

    $query = "insert into users(id,email) values(null,'$email')";
    $res_a = $dbcon->$query($query);

    if ( ! $res_a ) {  // testing for FALSE is only safe way
        throw new Exception($dbcon->error);
    }

    //$l_id = $res_a->insert_id;
    $l_id = $dbcon->insert_id;


    $query="insert into profiles values($l_id,'$name','$birthday')";
    $res_b=$dbcon->query($query);

    if( ! res_b) {
        throw new Exception($dbcon->error);
    }

    $dbcon->commit();

}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $dbcon->rollback();
}
finally{    // spelling correction
    // not strictly necessary as PHP will close and cleanup automatically
    if(isset($dbcon))
        $dbcon->close();
}
```

Comment: Finally it's work, the problem was in using $res_a->insert_id rather than $dbcon->insert_id ... thnx @RiggsFolly